# Dictionary and list merging difficulty?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I'm working on creating an information book using a dictionary and list. I'm having trouble with printing specific elements because of the list being the element.

```
book = {}
print("Welcome to the information book.\n"
    "To add your information, type : 'add'\n"
    "To look up the corporation, type: 'corp'\n"
    "To exit, type: 'end'\n")
menu = input("Enter a menu option stated above: ")
while menu.lower() != 'end':
    if menu.lower() == 'add':
        name = input("Enter your name here: ")
        userID = input("Enter your userID here: ")
        hours = input("Enter the amount of hours worked here: ")
        corporation = input("Enter the corporation name here: ")

        information = []
        information.append(name)
        information.append(hours)
        information.append(corporation)
        book[userID] = information
    elif menu.lower() == 'corp':
        searchFor = input("Enter the name here: ")
        for key in book:
            for element in book[key]:
                if searchFor.lower() == element.lower():
                    print("The corporation name for", searchFor, "is:",
                          information[2])
```

Now when I run and test my program to look for a person's corporate name, the corporate name for that person isn't correct, but is the corporate name of the last person who inputted their information.

Here is what the code looks like when it is executed:

```
Welcome to the information book.
To add your information, type: 'add'
To look up the corporation, type: 'corp'
To exit, type: 'end'

Enter a menu option stated above: add
Enter your name here: James Withson
Enter your userID here: Jwithso23
Enter the amount of hours worked here: 40
Enter the corporation name here: AMC

Enter a menu option stated above: add
Enter your name here: Blake O'boyle
Enter your userID here: Bboyle10
Enter the amount of hours worked here: 35
Enter the corporation name here: GMM

Enter a menu option stated above: corp
Enter the name here: James Withson
The corporation name for James Withson is: GMM
Enter a menu option stated above:
```

I tried concatenating the list to a new list every time the user added a new person and their information, however the main problem when I do that is I don't know which element is which if a user decides to look up a person's corporation. Any suggestions? thanks

### I can't use anything else as a key because of the fact that there can be the same name, corporation, hours worked.

Any other information that is needed, I will be happy to give. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Replace the last part of your code with

```
    elif menu.lower() == 'corp':
        searchFor = input("Enter the name here: ").lower()
        for info in book.values():
            if searchFor == info[0].lower():
                print("The corporation name for", searchFor, "is:", info[2])
```